# Check an event type of currently affected document in firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to check what was happened with currently affected document in Firestore collection?
Was it updated or it has created a new document?

For example to create a new document we can use this:

```
await db.collection('products').doc('xbox').set({ price: 300 });
```

I would like to get a feedback event for 2 following scenarios:

1. Creating a new document
   **Given** there is no document in `products` collection with a document id `xbox`
   **Then** it would create a new one.
2. Updating an existing document
   **Given** there is already an existing document with an id `xbox`.
   **Then** it should update it.

**The question is:**
How to get that info if it was **created** or **updated** ?

###### Real-life example when listening to Firestore

For example when listening to a realtime firestore updates, we can get that info like so:

```
db.collection('products').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    // Document write mode:
    console.log(change.type) // could be: added, modified, removed
  })
})
```

Is there something similiar tp `change.type` when modifying a document in firestore without actually listening to it but only using `.set()` ?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? `change.type` does seem to be useful in this case. `added` when new doc is created and `modified` when updated.

Comment: I do not want to use `listener`, `change.type` works only when you are listening to some db collection with `.onSnapshot(...)`.

Comment: So where are you trying to get that information?

Comment: Here: `db.collection('products').doc('xbox').set(data);`

Comment: One would around (which doesn't seem to be nice) would be to use `update()` first and then use `set()` if update fails because document does not exists. Cloud Firestore triggers for Cloud functions  can differentiate between those but I don't think that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) just returns `Promise<void>` so you cannot check if document is new or existing document was updated using that. You'll have to check for document's existence before using `set()`.

Comment: That was actually a problem, I want to reduce the reads over the Firestore by avoiding the checks, but I guess that's the only working way.

Comment: @aspirinemaga I'm not totally sure about your case but it might be resolved maybe by changing your logic a bit. Like the document ID has to a name instead of a random ID? So when listing existing products, the IDs would be there already. But when creating product, a document with that random ID won't exist for sure.